# Hashicorp Vault inject directory

Tags: devops, hashicorp-vault

I want to inject a whole directory using the agent injector.

I would, firstly, like to know if this is even possible.

I will explain myself:

I have this secrets directory: `/secret/dev/app/` and under `app`, I have `aws/some_secrets`, `db/some_secrets`, etc...

Is it possible to inject the app directory without having the full secret name?

Comment: What do you mean by "inject"? Where do you want to "inject" the secrets?

Comment: I'm using vault-agent as a sidecar to inject secrets into my pods.
all examples are showing how to inject a single secret, I'd like to know how to inject the whole directory.

Comment: It just looks like a directory to us humans. Each secret has a name, that may or may not contain `/`. I'm afraid you must iterate the secrets yourself (`vault list`).

Answer (score 0):

I would say take a look at Agent Templates.

If you take a look at step 7 of [the tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/agent-templates?in=vault/vault-agent#start-vault-agent):

```
{{ with secret "secret/data/customers/acme" }}
Organization: {{ .Data.data.organization }}
ID: {{ .Data.data.customer_id }}
Contact: {{ .Data.data.contact_email }}
{{ end }}
```

You could simply template this template file with a script then run the agent. But your script that generates the dynamic template file would have to do some heavy lifting...

List all secrets under a KV v2 basepath (if the engine mount path has no `/` characters in it):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
listall() {
  kv2opt="/metadata"
  if [ "${1}" = "-kv2" ]; then
    kv2opt="/metadata"
    shift
  elif [ "${1}" = "-kv1" ]; then
    kv2opt=""
    shift
  fi
  sarg=$(printf '%s' "${1}" | sed -E 's~/*$~~g' | sed -E 's~^/*~~g')
  engine=$(printf '%s' "${sarg}" | cut -d/ -f1 )
  if [ "$(printf '%s' "${sarg}" | cut -d/ -f2)" = "metadata" ]; then
    vpath=$(printf '%s' "${sarg}" | sed -E "s~^${engine}/metadata/?~~g" )
  else
    vpath=$(printf '%s' "${sarg}" | sed -E "s~^${engine}/?~~g" )
  fi
  curl -s -H "X-Vault-Request: true" -H "X-Vault-Token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}" --request LIST \
    "${VAULT_ADDR}/v1/${engine}${kv2opt}/${vpath}" | jq -rc '.data.keys[]' | while IFS= read -r li; do
    if [ "${li: -1}" != "/" ]; then
      printf "%s/%s\n" "${sarg}" "${li}"
    else
      listall "${sarg}/${li}"
    fi
  done
}
listall -kv2 "secret/dev/app" | while IFS= read -r path; do
  cat << EOF >> template.tpl
{{ with secret "${path}" }}
${path}: {{ .Data.data }}
{{ end }}
EOF
done
```

...and then maybe run the resultant `template.tpl` file through the Vault Agent using the template process. But that's pretty useless if things have to be read by a machine after the template finishes, so you may need to have a new loop read each secret to figure out what the *keys* are on each secret. And then do some advanced formatting. However, the way you structured your question, this technically answers it, and you can figure out how to do the rest (or reframe your question, or ask a new question).